# Ubuntu error: "filename" cannot execute binary file

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, sift

I am working on matlab R2013a on Ubuntu. I am referring this code:

```
sift_bin = fullfile('lib/sift/bin/siftfeat');   
[pf,nf,ef] = fileparts(filename);
desc_file = [fullfile(pf,nf) '.txt'];
im1=imread(filename);
if (size(im1,1)<=1000 && size(im1,2)<=1000)
    status1 = system([sift_bin ' -x -o ' desc_file ' ' filename]);
else
    status1 = system([sift_bin ' -d -x -o ' desc_file ' ' filename]);
end
```

But it gives an error:

```
lib/sift/bin/siftfeat cannot execute binary file
```

Is there anything wrong with system call?

lib/sift/bin/siftfeat is a path of sift library.

Comment: Are you missing a forward slash before lib or is that supposed to be a relative path?

Comment: Did you download the binaries for the right architecture? Do you get the same error, if you run the command via linux terminal? I think it's an issue with the binaries, not with your matlab code.

Comment: Giving same error while running on the command via terminal

Answer (score 1):

Use `file` utility to make sure that file is an executable and see its architecture

```
system('file /bin/ls')
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
(uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
BuildID[sha1]=0xf31e99218b4d7034cf8257055686bca22f5a3c01, stripped
ans = 0
```

Then `uname -a` shows architecture of your system

```
system('uname -a')
Linux optiPlex7010 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013
x86_64   x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ans = 0
```

As one can see I have 64-bit Linux and executable is also 64-bit. However, when it comes to 32-bit systems and executable support is backward compatible. That means 64-bit system may execute both 32-bit and 64-bit executables, but 32-bit system can execute only 32-bit executables.

From your comments I see that you are trying to launch 64-bit executable in 32-bit system, which is not capable of doing that. You should find 32-bit version of `siftfeat` or change your OS to 64-bit, if that is possible.

Comment: all checked.but couldn't find where the problem is.

Comment: I tried all these conditions,for dot calls it is same error, for system('file /bin/ls') output is - /bin/ls: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x83531f308f1fa18221be53eaf399303400c14638, stripped
status1 =  0

Comment: OUTPUT is: lib/sift/bin/siftfeat: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x34f774d3c6d2665c2b811bbd78ddf6a37d437b7f, not stripped
status is 0

Comment: Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-58-generic-pae #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 18:00:02 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: See an updated answer. Could you please also add `system('uname -a')` and `system('file lib/sift/bin/siftfeat')` to the question, so it would be easy for other people to see the full problem?

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate your effort. Thank you for responding.

Comment: definitely...Thank you.As soon as i get privileges i will vote up your answer.Thank you for your response